# Changes doesn't take effect unless I put " !important " tag. Why?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a simple navigation bar in CSS. in my custom StyleSheet(style.css) the following change do not take effect. I used Bootstrap in HTML markup :

```css
ul.nav li a:hover {
    background: #2E9AFE; /* Don't work in style.css*/
    color: white; /* Don't work in style.css*/
    }
```

But when I place the `!important` tag, it works. Why it doesn't work on previous one?

```css
ul.nav li a:hover {
    background: #2E9AFE !important; /* This Works */
    color: white !important; /* This Works */
}
```

Comment: Is your CSS loaded before or after Bootstrap's?

Comment: COZ it get from Bootstrap which higher priority

Comment: my css is loaded before Bootstrap's . @j08691

Comment: Still No luck !! Not working Either. @j08691

Comment: Then Bootstraps selector must be more specific than yours. You can either use !important, or come up with a more specific selector.

Comment: what is bootstrap's selector?

Comment: Yup, used more specific selector and now working good. Thanks :) @j08691

Answer (score 0):

**TRY**

```
 .ur-namedivmore-specifc-divname ul.nav li a:hover {
       background: #2E9AFE !important; /* This will Works */
       color: white !important; /* This will Works */
}
```

To over ride the property of any other css file (in ur case bootstrap.css) or plugin ! you need to use more specif parent selector to target and override the properties.

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: @ Taryn East valued ur comment (Y) . but div name itself cleared the msg but yeah you are right :)

Answer (score 0):

1) Check the order of which your stylesheet loads. The Browser by way of the DOM will scan through each stylesheet in order from top to bottom.

Note: If an identical element(class, id, tag etc.) exists in multiple stylesheets && shares the same property(ex: background), the last loaded stylesheet's corresponding value will be expressed. (ex: if *bootstrap's* ul.nav li a:hover {background: #ffffff;} and *your* ul.nav li a:hover {background: #2E9AFE;}), the document will display the last one it loads(the lowest stylesheet on the document).

2) The **!important** caveat will overwrite this cascading rule. Use it with caution and sparingly, it will overwrite any sheets that are cascaded after itself...unless those sheets also use !important on the same element's property.

If I were to guess, you likely loaded your 'stylesheet.css' stylesheet before bootstrap.

Your markup should be in this order:

```
<style src=".../bootstrap.css" />
<style src=".../style.css" />
```

Once you load your stylesheets property, try adding a class to your navigation anchor tags you want the hover effect to apply to
  Ex:

```
/*style*/  .nav-hover-link { background: #2E9AFE; color: white;}
<!-- markup--> <a class="nav-hover-link"></a>
```

***The browser will be able execute this task faster than your original css because it will only be looking for that specific class, rather than having to look through all your unordered lists, all your navs, all your lists and then all your anchors.